# How To Reduce File Size For A Custom Sticker App

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio

I've built a custom iMessage sticker app that has hundreds of stickers and requires an in-app purchase to unlock them.  As I'm adding more and more stickers, my app size is obviously increasing.  I'm doing my best to compress images and keep the file size down but trying to think of other ways to keep a low file size.

I came across this sticker app:

Apple: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mojilala-unlimited-10000+/id1153431461?mt=8&_branch_match_id=598750316922589452

Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.leo.stickers&hl=en

It has 42,000 stickers but the file size is only around 22MB.  It works like a normal sticker app too, you can't tell a difference.

I'm very new to coding and have no idea what to even research to have something like this for my app.  Could the stickers be hosted on a WordPress site and a link to the image be sent to the app somehow?  Is this something Firebase could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how the above mentioned app works. But I think you can use the following approaches:

- Only add the free stickers to the app, and download the others from the server when user purchases it.
- Slightly different approach from the above one, add the low resolution thumbnails to the app. When user launches your app for the first time download the actual stickers in the background and show them after the successful download. Add some logic to check whether any new stickers available to download when your app is launched each time and act accordingly.

For iOS there are several methods to reduce the app size, please check this [Technical Q & A](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1795/_index.html)

Answer (score -1):

Use **Firebase Cloud Storage** to upload your stickers as images. You can download those images and display them in your app. Go through the [Firebase Cloud Storage Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) for the details.

Comment: The idea of downloading is fine, but the advertisement for firebase is unneeded.   Download them from anywhere, a normal web download would be fine.

Comment: @GabeSechan The OP clearly asked in his question **Is this something Firebase could do?** So what's the problem if the answerer added the same in his answer ? In my opinion Firebase is one of the best tool to implement this in both platforms (iOS & Android)

Comment: All he needs is to download files, adding in a 3rd part dependency and an entire infrastructure dependency on a company known to throw away infrastrucutre projects on a whim is a pretty bad idea.  ANd its quite evident from his question that he isn't looking at firebase as an answer, its just something he's vaguely heard of.  All he needs here is a webserver, anything else is overcomplicating things.

Comment: @GabeSechan It can/cannot happen, that doesn't matter, since the OP asked for firebase explicitly in the question. What happened to parse ? Nothing is permanent in this industry, so may be they will throw away firebase or even android, but not too soon.

Comment: I'm only worried because of your comment, everyone has their own freedom in this community to suggest the solution that they think is the best. Freedom of choice. But calling that as an advertisement doesn't look good.